Extending Volume Group RHEL LVM
I got a production server (RHEL) with below FS configuration df -h:
# df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                         7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            7.9G  752K  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvroot            40G  4.2G   36G  11% /
/dev/sda2                       1014M  291M  724M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvvar             20G  1.1G   19G   6% /var
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvhome            40G  318M   40G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvvar_tmp         10G  104M  9.9G   2% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvvar_log         10G  314M  9.7G   4% /var/log
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvvar_log_audit   10G  524M  9.5G   6% /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/vg0-lvtmp             20G  176M   20G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1190376420

also:
# ll /dev/sd*
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Jul  8 12:21 /dev/sda
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  1 Jul  8 12:21 /dev/sda1
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  2 Jul  8 12:21 /dev/sda2
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  3 Jul  8 12:21 /dev/sda3
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Jul 10 10:27 /dev/sdb

as you see /dev/sdb is not formated and mounted in filesystem. however as this is production server I need to make sure from professional this specific case. what is the best way to use /dev/sdb to extend / (root) and /home/ file systems. below is the stat:
# pvs
  PV         VG  Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda3  vg0 lvm2 a--  <199.00g <17.00g

# lvs
  LV              VG  Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lvhome          vg0 -wi-ao---- 40.00g
  lvroot          vg0 -wi-ao---- 40.00g
  lvswap          vg0 -wi-ao---- 32.00g
  lvtmp           vg0 -wi-ao---- 20.00g
  lvvar           vg0 -wi-ao---- 20.00g
  lvvar_log       vg0 -wi-ao---- 10.00g
  lvvar_log_audit vg0 -wi-ao---- 10.00g
  lvvar_tmp       vg0 -wi-ao---- 10.00g

# vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  vg0   1   8   0 wz--n- <199.00g <17.00g

I want to use half of /dev/sdb to extend / and the other half for /home.

From what I understand, you 1st need to create the PV on /dev/sdb, then add it in the VG, and then add half of the device for / & /home.
pvcreate /dev/sdb
vgextend vg0 /dev/sdb

then you can extend each LV using half of /dev/sdb size and resize the FS at once (-r option) where Size can be m or g
lvextend -L +Size /dev/mapper/vg0-lvroot -r
lvextend -L +Size /dev/mapper/vg0-lvhome -r

